# Composing commands in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's a *really* common use case for me to copy-and-paste some JSON string in a new VSCode buffer, and wanting to see it pretty-printed.

So it's a *really* common thing for me to change the new buffer's Language Mode to JSON (`CMD+Shift+O`, type "Language" for `Change Language Mode` command, type `JSON` + `Enter`), then `Format Document` (`CMD+Shift+O`, `format`, `Enter`).

I'd like to set a new function/shortcut that makes all of that at once. **Is there an easy way to do that without writing a whole extension?**

Comment: Probably not: [Expose change language command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1800), [Chaining commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/871)

Answer (score 1):

Not as of VS Code 1.29. You need to use one of the extensions.

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/871) tracks built-in support for chaining commands